# Char* and While Loop is not working with eachother

Tags: c++

Here is code which compare s2 with s1, if they are the same it returns 0 and some other options, but while loop is not end-able and I can not find its problem, the only thing I know if I convert char* s2 into const char* s2 it will work fine.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int cmp(char*,char*);
int main()
{
    char* s1;
    cout << "Please Enter First Word: "; cin >> s1;
    char* s2;
    cout << "Please Enter Second Word: "; cin >> s2;
    cout << "The Result is: " << cmp(s1,s2) << endl;
       return 0;
}

int cmp(char* s1, char* s2)
{
    int i=0;
    while (*(s2+i)!=0)
    {
        if (*(s2+i)>*(s1+i)) return 1;
        if (*(s2+i)<*(s1+i)) return -1;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `strcmp` which is standard, and equivalent to your `cmp`? And `std::string` has `compare` also...

Comment: You are using `s1` and `s2` before initializing them to a sensible value.

Comment: This is probably the most common mistake I see in C and C++ code on SO.  Unfortunately it's hard to search for if you don't already know what the problem is.

Comment: @Stranger what is your question. or where you're getting wrong?

Comment: If you compile with `-Wall` you'd likely get some helpful warnings.

Comment: the while loop will not end and it will continue till overflow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider:

```
char* s1;
cout << "Please Enter First Word: "; cin >> s1;
```

How big is `s1` ? The problem is that your char pointers doesn't point to any memory block. You need to allocate memory with `new`.

Answer (score 5):

You have **undefined behaviour**.  You aren't allocating any space to store the string (you're not initialising `s1` or `s2` to point at any memory).

I suggest using `std::string` instead; it manages its own memory issues.

Answer (score 1):

As above said by Oli and karlphillip, your code must allocate memory for strings.

And the `compare` function can be like....

```
int cmp(char* s1, char* s2) 
{ 
    int i=0; 

    while ( *(s1+i)!=0 & *(s2+i)!=0 ) 
    { 
        if (*(s2+i)>*(s1+i)) return 1; 
        if (*(s2+i)<*(s1+i)) return -1; 
        i++; 
    } 
    if(*(s1+i)==0 & *(s2+i)==0 )
     return 0;
    else if (*(s1+i)!=0)
     return -1;
    else
     return 1;
}
```

Because, your `cmp` function will `return 0` whenever your str1 is greater in length that str2 and str1 is identical to str2 upto str2's length.